# NuxtJS mixin Issue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently facing a weird issue with NuxtJS.

After creating a mixing for a component I can access / print a field from the components data.

```js
export default () => {
  return {
    head () {
      console.log(this.story)
    }
  }
}
```

Works fine.
But after I try to access the object `story` itself, it becomes undefined.

```js
export default () => {
  return {
    head () {
      console.log(this.story)
      const title = this.story.content.title
      console.log(title)
    }
  }
}
```

> Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

The log statement of `this.story` is then undefined too.

The component where I registered this mixin makes use of another one with return the `story` data field.

```js
export default{
  name: 'Default',
  components: {Page},
  mixins: [
    FetchData({
      preview: false
    }),
    addMetaTags()
  ]
}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: `this.story` is probably not defined yet when you `console.log` it? At which point is your mixin creating your `story`, lifecycle-wise.

Comment: in the async fetch() hook

Comment: btw console.log(obj) does not log a string representation, it logs a reference to the actual javascript object in the memory. So any changes made to the object will get reflected in the logged instance. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528322/javascript-console-log-gives-different-results-than-alert) answer.
Debugging with console.log is therefore not really a good idea.

Comment: I'm not sure which one is done before the other. You could maybe check the status of `$fetchState.pending` and see if it returns anything at all. Also yeah, @braks is right on this one. Either stringify or alertify it, who know. :D

Comment: :Braks I know thanks. The console statement is just for the matter of purpose to demonstrate the error behaviour. 
:kissu Exact same behaviour. At first it is called with undefined and immediately after it is "false"

Comment: Yep, so probably something to do with lifecycles.